# ARIMA for more than one categories python using for loop

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
Sector    Jan    Feb    March     April   May   June   July  August   September
SE1       8      12     15        20      6      1     5     8        15 
SE2       5      3      15        2       16     11    5     18       15 
SE3       2      12     10        1       8      21    15    8        2
```

From the above I would like to write a python code to do any univariate Time series forecasting for each categories in a for month October and November.

Expected Output:

```
Sector    October      November
SE1       20           24
SE2       13           9
SE1       1            4
```

The above forecasted value I have entered is arbitrary, I would like to have that comes from time series forecasting algorithm.

Comment: Do you have your model of time series prepared? or do you want to create your model using the info in your data frame?

Comment: @Andrex I don't have my model, I very new in python and machine learning. I would like to create a model (any forecasting model) for this dataframe